# Efficient way of decoding a dynamically changing data model in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, jsondecoder

I need to display a dynamically changing data model received from a Socketserver in form of a JSON object.
The general structure of the data model will remain the same `[[String:String]]`, only dictionary items might get added or deleted.

So far I have utilised the `Codable` protocol to take care of parsing data from the server with a rigid `struct`.

• Is using an instance of `JSONSerialization` the best way to go here?
• Or would it be possible to write a custom `init()` for a `struct` that let's it dynamically take properties from a an array received from the server, and then use `JSONDecoder` to decode the data?

The latter would be more convenient solution for me because I already have some function in the struct that do more tasks with the data model, but the function could be integrated in a ViewModel `class`.

Comment: For this task `JSONSerialization` is indeed the best way because you can enumerate (arbitrary) keys and values.

Comment: _"Or would it be possible to write a custom init()..."_, how can we possibly answer this with the given information? Only you knows if it is possible depending on what "dynamically changing" really means and if it would be worth the effort compared to using JSONSerialization.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson The data model will keep it's general structure of `[[String:String]]`, only dictionary items might get added or deleted (As mentioned above).

What I was wondering with the second question/soultion-approach would look something like this:
`let headers: [String] = ["Name", "Age", "Height"];

init() {
    for header in headers {
        self.header = jsonResp[header]
    }
}`
I was wondering if there was a way to implement that, obviously `header` in that case is a `String` and can't be used to declare a property

Comment: Can you please show the json you want to decode?